# Which Sutta does Sakkra asks 14 Questions from the Buddha?

Tags: reference-request, meditation-insight, craving

In [Maha Buddhavamsa The Great Chronicle of The Buddhas](http://www.bps.lk/olib/mi/mi014.pdf) by Tipitakadhara Mingun Sayadaw, page 949 to 980, there is a series of question between the Buddha and Sakkra. This seems very relevant to the Buddhist meditation practice. Which Suttas does this conversation appear in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sakka-pañha Sutta: Sakka's Questions.

http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.21.2x.than.html

Answer (score 0):

As per the Story of the Youth Magha... It is found in the Dhammapada Commentary – in Book II. Heedfulness, Appamāda Vagga. Under that chapter  II. 7. Is about [“How Magha Became Sakka”](http://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/English-Texts/Buddhist-Legends/02-07.htm).
You could also read about it [**HERE**](http://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/English-Texts/Buddhist-Legends/Buddhist-Legends-1.pdf)